# why user interaction will block http request in local eventloop in qt

Tags: c++, qt

Just like the code below, once the UI shows up, I keep resizing the window with mouse. And then it will be blocking in `loop.exec(QEventLoop::ExcludeUserInputEvents);` forever which will never receive QNetworkReply's finished signal, in the meantime the whole UI is suspended.

And then if I press the keys like alt+tab to switch the window, finished signal will be received at once and everything will be all right. In the period of suspending, the timer still work, it will still print "hello", so it means user's interaction wiil not block the timer but only the http request.

I have tested this in both Qt 5.12.0 and Qt 5.13.1, and the results are the same. Is it a bug with Qt or there is something wrong with the code.

I know it is a better choice to use signal-slot async way, but this is a part of base code of our project. It is hard to change it from sync to async.

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QTimer::singleShot(3*1000, this, &MainWindow::onPushButtonCliecked);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::onPushButtonCliecked()
{
    qDebug()<<"start";
    QString text;
    QNetworkAccessManager manager;
    QNetworkRequest request(QUrl("http://10.86.0.109:28090/iptable_mgr/"));
    QNetworkReply *reply = manager.get(request);
    QEventLoop loop;
    connect(reply, &QNetworkReply::finished, &loop, &QEventLoop::quit);
    QTimer timer;
    timer.setInterval(1*1000);
    connect(&timer, &QTimer::timeout, []{ qDebug()<<"hello"; });
    timer.start();
    loop.exec(QEventLoop::ExcludeUserInputEvents);
    if (reply->error() != QNetworkReply::NoError)
        text = ("error" + reply->errorString());
    else
        text = ("response" + reply->readAll());
    delete reply;
    qDebug()<<text;
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of running your own even loop? Why not simply use the applications main event loop, and connect `QNetworkReply::finished` to a slot in your `MainWindow` class that handles the reply?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude That is a well-documented way of doing synchronous network requests `QNetworkAccessManager`. I'm not convinced the resize events will block HTTP though.

Comment: Somewhat unrelated to the question: I'd avoid local event loops like the plague. All they bring reentrancy issues and pain. Use a separate slot or lambda instead.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution to this: replace eventloop with processEvents. And I add `isTimeOut` to check if it is overtime.

```
    //loop.exec(QEventLoop::ExcludeUserInputEvents);
    do
    {
        if (reply->isFinished() || isTimeOut())
        {
            break;
        }
        QCoreApplication::processEvents();
    } while (1);
```